# Javascript not executing after .load with specific Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When trying to use `load()` to load a specific element from a page the javascript on that page wont execute.

```js
$.(thread).load("localhost:8085/thread.php#thread_entries")
```

It loads the content just fine but some javascript (Thats contained inside of the `#thread_entries` div) wont execute.

The example code I'm using to test it at the moment:

```html
...
<div id="thread_entries">
    <div id="text">Texty text</div>
    <script>
        console.log("hussah!!!");

            function manualDropZone() {
                $('#<?php echo $id; ?> .dropzone').filedropbox({
                    url: 'ajax.php/form/upload/<?php echo $this->field->get( 'id' ) ?>',
                    link: $('#<?php echo $id; ?>').find("a.manual"),
                    paramname: "upload[]",
                    fallback_id: 'file-<?php echo $id; ?>',
                    allowedfileextensions: <?php echo JsonDataEncoder::encode(
                        $config['__extensions'] ?: array() ); ?>,
                    allowedfiletypes: <?php echo JsonDataEncoder::encode(
                        $mimetypes ); ?>,
                    maxfiles: <?php echo $config['max'] ?: 20; ?>,
                    maxfilesize: <?php echo $maxfilesize; ?>,
                    name: '<?php echo $name; ?>[]',
                    files: <?php echo JsonDataEncoder::encode( $files ); ?>
                });
            }
    </script>
</div>
...
```

Loading the javascript separately with getscript is not an option since the javascript itself depends on some php variables from that page.

Comment: Please check the documentation, specially the section on [**load - Script Execution**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - *If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.* -  Your selector expression is `#thread_entries`

Comment: You dont happen to have tips about how to go around this?

Comment: You could use the `load()` callback to execute `getScript()` to load the *.js file you need. If your script is embedded in the source page then I don't know.

Comment: yea its an embedded script, guess ill go at it in a roundabout way and have it import the script as a div and insert it into a Script tag